# Bold table row using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am tring to bold the row of a table when click.
What shall I do to let the script know which row I click? 
The only way I can think of is using function as below.

```
<script>
function bold(x){
    $("#"+x).click(function(e){ 
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        e.stopPropagation(); 
       });
   }
</script>
<table>
<tr id = 1 onclick = bold(this.id)><td>A</td></tr>
<tr id = 2 onclick = bold(this.id)><td>B</td></tr>
<tr id = 3 onclick = bold(this.id)><td>C</td></tr>
<tr id = 4 onclick = bold(this.id)><td>D</td></tr>
<tr id = 5 onclick = bold(this.id)><td>E</td></tr>
<tr id = 6 onclick = bold(this.id)><td>F</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there any better way to do it without using function?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$('tr').click(function(e){ 
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        e.stopPropagation(); 
 });
```

Also you are enclosing your id's in Quotes.. Do that first

`<tr id = "1" onclick = bold(this.id)><td>A</td></t`r>

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/eF9FN/1/)

Accoring to HTML5 standards it's not necessary to enclose in Quotes.. But I think it's a good practice to do so..

Comment: Oh no that was such a simple yet effective solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should tidy up your html..

html

```
<table>
<tr><td>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td></tr>
<tr><td>E</td></tr>
<tr><td>F</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​
```

javascript

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){
   $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
})​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

See [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A6yDt/)

```
$('table td').on('click', function(){
      $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the documentation for [jQuery's on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which provides a much cleaner way to attach handlers to elements. Using that, you can remove the `onclick` attributes, and attach the behavior to the elements directly from the javascript. Following from your example:

```
<script>
  $("tr").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
  });
</script>
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td></tr>
  <tr><td>E</td></tr>
  <tr><td>F</td></tr>
</table>
```

Note that no ids or `onclick` handlers are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function(e){ 
    $("td", $(this)).css("font-weight","bold");
 });
```

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation to your answer.